# Passing `git blame` options to `git gui blame`

Tags: git, git-gui, git-blame

How can I pass `git blame` options such as `-C` to `git gui blame`? Merely typing

```
git gui blame -C somefile
```

results in

> error: unknown switch `-C'
>
> usage: git cat-file ...

Answer (score 1):

I see the `--line=x` option is supported for [`git gui blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui#Documentation/git-gui.txt-blame), but other [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) options seem not to be included.

See [`git-gui/git-gui.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ff66981f4593aec0f3b3eeace0eacb7dbe44fd8c/git-gui/git-gui.sh#L3067-L3072)

```
if {$subcommand eq "blame"} {
    set subcommand_args {[--line=<num>] rev? path}
} else {
    set subcommand_args {rev? path}
}
```